# How to remote debug WebLogic server when it started as Windows Service

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, windows-server-2008-r2

I tried almost all internet and stackoverflow tips and no one didn't help me to open ports in Weblogic Server. My Weblogic server starts as windows service in windows server 2008 r2. In config.xml on the path
..user_projects\domains\%Any_app%\config\config.xml i added this string for each server in arguments  -

```
<server-start>
      <arguments>... -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1777,server=y,suspend=n ...
     </arguments>
</server-start>
```

and i always check in cmd with netstate -a or telnet this port but it doesn't appear and doesn't work.

Comment: Did you remove and re-create each service for each server after updating your config ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Nope i just restarted server but on admin server in console i see my changes in server\configuration\Server_Start\Arguments

Comment: your weblogic conf is ok, but your windows service is not i think. Once you have changed your server configuration you must remove and recreate the windows service. Startup arguments are part of the service configuration. Updating only the weblogic domain conf is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to edit regedit with my weblogic as win service. Path:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/services/%Name_of_service% and here u can edit settings
(add some strings in setting fields) and then restart machine with u server.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, check your firewall - ensure that port is open.

Second, check config.xml again, then in administration console go to

Servers - Configuration - Listen Port - made modifications if needed.

Restart weblogic. Check if service is started, if not then modify windows [service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe).

Read this article how to manage [ports](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/ASADM/ports.htm#ASADM482).

Change the port number with WLST, if it possible for you.